# Getting null error in the array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I get this strange error: Cannot read property 'includes' of null in my react application. However, I am 100% sure my objects in the array contains FirstName field.

The values come from props is an array of object like that:

`[{ Id: 1, FirstName: "A" }, {Id: 2, FirstName: "X"} ] // this what comes from props`

```
let myVar = this.props.values.filter(val=> val.FirstName === "X"); // works
let myVar = this.props.values.filter(val=> val.FirstName.includes("X") // Cannot read property 'includes' of null

console.log(myVar) // works (prints out the object as the first element of the array
console.log(myVar[0].FirstName) //  Cannot read property 'FirstName' of undefined
```

What I am missing?

Comment: 1)Have to tried logging the object in console before filtering. 2)And you are missing `)`.

Comment: Your example seems incomplete,you're defining values as a local variable (`let values`) but are accessing something through `this.props.values`. Make sure you provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You are also declaring `myVar` twice. Which should have thrown an error

Comment: @EyasSH sorry, I just wanted to give an example data that comes from the props.

Comment: @MaheerAli ignore the ")".

Comment: @newbie35 give us codepen we can't say anything

Comment: @MaheerAli why don't you want to understand I gave these to give you an idea. You are saying I declared myVar twice. Really

Comment: the question is not providing the information required to answer the question, for example, what is x, how the function calls in react etc

Comment: @newbie35 what's wrong, it seems working fine here https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b4nnfx?file=Hello.js

Comment: @Jayavel Yes it definitely works, check my answer I believe it must be the fact that whatever he's passing into props as `values` is not an array with static values  - they must be fetched from a backend or a public API or something. Before the fetch is ready and the array has values these errors tend to occur when you try to do operations such as `.includes`.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet below works for me, simply editing your code to not read from props:

```
    let values = [{ Id: 1, FirstName: 'A' }, { Id: 2, FirstName: 'X' }];

    let myVar = values.filter((val) => val.FirstName === 'X'); // works
    let myVar = values.filter((val) => val.FirstName.includes('X')); // Cannot read property 'includes' of null

    console.log('myVar', myVar); // works (prints out the object as the first element of the array
    console.log('myVar firstName', myVar[0].FirstName);
```

So this means the source of the issue is coming from your props - if the data is set in statically like in your example, using `let values = [{ Id: 1, FirstName: 'A' }, { Id: 2, FirstName: 'X' }];` both ways work properly.

I can think of a couple reasons why this is happening. Is your props coming from a http request to another endpoint (to an API)? When your data is not static and is fetched from an API you need to provide a check to make the the values are ready before trying to access their properties.

E.g. if your props is supposed to have fetched an array back but before the get request is complete you are trying to access the information with `includes` when it is still null.

If you are infact retrieving data and passing it on as props try:

```
if(values) {
   values.filter((val) => val.FirstName.includes('X'));
}
```

Making sure the data is not null or undefined before you perform any operations on it.

If this doesn't fix your issue try make a check for the `val` object in each iteration, making sure each exist and have a FistName before you try and access the `.includes`.

Something you can try:

```
// check that values array is ready from api get request
if(values) {
   values.filter((val) => {
      // check if val has a first name - if error there is your reason
      if(val.FirstName) {
         return val.FirstName.includes('X');
      }

   });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am getting these values form an API but still doesn't work! JS engine enters this if block however, still sees null

Comment: Ok well we are half way there now. After it enters the if block, console log the `values` array before you even filter it. Let's debug this thing. If it is null there how could it have gone into the if block right. If it's not null also try log each `val` INSIDE the filter. You will need a multiline return instead of a single line arrow function to both log and return so:
`
values.filter((val) => {
   console.log(val);
   return val.FirstName.includes('X');
});
`
Make sure they aren't null before you access the FirstName.includes.

Comment: Did you set default value for this `values` variable? Because `if([])` return true

Comment: Don,'t worry @TamDc I wrote a long condition values !== null && values !== undefined && values !== "" && values !== []

Comment: Can you show us the `console.log(values)` before it filtered?

Comment: I gave up! Thanks.